# Strategy for separating common logic across multiple websites

Tags: asp.net

I have a scenario where I have multiple websites using a commnon dll for authentication and general user detail fetching.

I now need to update the common dll with a slightly different login logic and it means I'll need to push this new dll into every website and do a release process for each.

I'm wondering whether it's better to host the common authentication methods in a webservice of some sort then have the websites call that internally.  Would it be an internal web service?  ajax callbacks from an server side only website? Or stick with the dll method to ensure code changes doesn't break the sites?

Are there any security concerns when not using a dll for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches work in my opinion, but there are significant differences between them that we should keep in mind.

First of all, all of this depends also on the language you are using, because sometimes the best theoretical answer is not always easily implemented in each and every language, making it practical unusable.

So, with this in mind, the best way for me is to have an **internal web service**, who deals with all requests regarding this "authentication and general user detail module", assuming that all websites use the same DB (or data layer) (otherwise, you will need to create a web service for each one and it's another completely different story). This approach will give you **flexibility** and **maintainability**. You could use direct ajax requests to this web service, or make the calls from you website server, and them reply to the browser already with that information. (this second option is more time consuming but much more secure, and if it is a real internal web service (ie hosted on the same machine, the lag will not be noticeable)).

The dll approach should if you need to apply the same business logic to different services. In practical terms: you have two completely separated web sites, that use the same kind of authentication logic. Keep in mind that using this approach to websites that use the same data layer, will force you most of the times to have "deprecated ways" working together with the new implementations, while you are updating the dll on all websites.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Using a webservice seems a good way to do that. I will cause less memory usage and can be updated independantly from the wesites (if ever needed).

You could go for a WCF services (with dual tcp?) maybe.